# Does tapping the Yellow bird sooner have a greater impact on the structure?

Tags: angry-birds

If I click earlier to launch the extra speed for the yellow bird,
will it have a greater impact or does it matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't matter, as far as I know. There's two things to keep in mind with yellow birds:

1. They are only effective against certain materials. They will rip
   through wood but seem to be particularly weak against ice.
2. When you choose to click on the bird after launching it determines what kind of trajectory the bird will have; apart from going backwards, you can make a yellow bird strike a target at pretty much any angle.

Comment: Yep, the important thing is trajectory.  Sometimes you might think that clicking earlier or later gives you more power but really it's just a more effective angle/position.